# How to click a line segment when close?

Tags: leaflet, line, select-by-location

I am looking for help to modify mouse click so that I can click a line segment without having to be directly over it.

I have been looking at Leaflet.AlmostOver but have been having difficulty getting it integrated.

Has anyone done this and have any suggestions on how I might resolve my issue?

Comment: Please be more specific about the technology stack you are using. To be clear you are designing a web map/application with Leaflet?

Comment: Correct.  I am designing with Leaflet.  Here is the code that I am attempting to modify to go from a pure lat/long selection to allowing a near to lat/long selection.  The goal is to be able to select a line segment layer without having to have the cursor directly over it.

Comment: fn: function (e) {
      if (!App.isTouch) {
        var latLng = e.latlng;
        
        document.getElementById('lat').innerHTML = latLng.lat.toFixed(4);
        document.getElementById('lng').innerHTML = latLng.lng.toFixed(4);
        document.getElementById('latLng').style.display = 'block';
      }
    },